Conveying 'odds and ends'
In the context of a mathematics blog, "odds and ends" typically refers to miscellaneous topics or a collection of various mathematical insights, tips, problems, curiosities, and discussions that don't necessarily fit into a single, coherent theme or larger article.
Examples of usage,
https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/contents/

How to convey 'odds and ends' in such contexts?

Could you transcribe or highlight the relevant part of the screenshot for accessibility?  Or reference similar phrases like bits and bobs, this and that? S'il s'agit d'un peu de tout j'ai du mal à le lire (à la recherche des lunettes perdues )!

If the "Odds and Ends" items are website links, the translation would be liens divers.
If not, Divers may work.

Other possibilities are Vrac or Bazar.

Or Divers et variés, mirroring the pleonasm in the original idiom. @Graffito It has a fr.Wikt entry, you may want to link to it in your answer.

You have several options:

Miscellanées has the exact meaning and register of "Miscellanea",
Fonds de tiroirs are leftovers, the wreckage of domestic incidents stored just in case; the idiom suggests a small collection of unpaired socks at the bottom of a drawer,
bric-à-brac is a collection of unclassified items, with no discernible plan in their presentation; like e. g. the contents for sale at a 2nd-hand dealer's or pawnbroker's, in the retail shop of a junkyard, etc.

